# Is the constructor of a class called if you declare a object of that class as an instance variable of another class?

Tags: c++

For example, if i have a class like this;

```
#import "B.h"
class A
{
    B object;
};
```

would B's constructor get called when I created a A object?

Comment: -1 for missing research. Any introduction to C++ will mention this.

Comment: Well, not any, at least the one I read didn't mention it. And believe me or not, I have done research.
Btw, thanks for posting why you have downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the default constructor will be called (if present) or a compiler error will be triggered if there is no default constructor for `B`.

Comment: It's been a while since I touched C++ but I'm sure that the default constructor is always provided implicitly, unless you create your own constructor, then the default is yanked away.

Comment: @PaulG: You are right. The compiler will *declare* a default constructor if no other constructor is provided, and it will *define* it if *used*, which is the case. It might on the other hand, do something or nothing at all (think POD types). I will update the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One way to test this is to put some simple cout calls in the constructors to watch the constructor calls happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, member constructor is called in order of declaration for the containing class.

Answer (score 0):

One should mention that this rule apply both ways, calling class 'A's destructor calls its members default destructor's.